# Ubuntu not booting after installation alongside windows 10

Tags: boot

Hi I am new to this site and linux as well. Installed ubuntu on my dell inspiron 3543 laptop which already had windows 10. After successfully installing ubuntu and at the first reboot, It started to boot windows 10 as usual and there was no option to select between ubuntu and windows 10.

Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode? And then did you from UEFI boot menu often f12 choose to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you tell me how to install in UEFI mode. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the link above. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI How you boot install media from UEFI boot menu to boot flash drive is then how it installs.

Comment: Many thanks oldfred. I'll try and get back to you. thanks again.

Comment: Many thanks oldfred, your link helped me install ubuntu and showed the grub menu on boot. Thanks very much. Your help is much appreciated.